# Different datatypes of dataframe columns are not support for Impute(handling missing value method) in Julia

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

I did one small experiment and I got to know that it is just because the different data types of columns include in CSV. please see the following code

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(:a => [1.0, 2, missing, missing, 5.0], :b => [1.1, 2.2, 3, missing, 5],:c => [1,3,5,missing,6])
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │ c       │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │ Int64?  │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0      │ 1.1      │ 1       │
│ 2   │ 2.0      │ 2.2      │ 3       │
│ 3   │ missing  │ 3.0      │ 5       │
│ 4   │ missing  │ missing  │ missing │
│ 5   │ 5.0      │ 5.0      │ 6       │

julia> df
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │ c       │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │ Int64?  │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0      │ 1.1      │ 1       │
│ 2   │ 2.0      │ 2.2      │ 3       │
│ 3   │ missing  │ 3.0      │ 5       │
│ 4   │ missing  │ missing  │ missing │
│ 5   │ 5.0      │ 5.0      │ 6       │

julia> using Impute

julia> Impute.interp(df)
ERROR: InexactError: Int64(5.5)
Stacktrace:
 [1] Int64 at ./float.jl:710 [inlined]
 [2] convert at ./number.jl:7 [inlined]
 [3] convert at ./missing.jl:69 [inlined]
 [4] setindex! at ./array.jl:826 [inlined]
 [5] (::Impute.var"#58#59"{Int64,Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}})(::Impute.Context) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors/interp.jl:67
 [6] (::Impute.Context)(::Impute.var"#58#59"{Int64,Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}}) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/context.jl:227
 [7] _impute!(::Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}, ::Impute.Interpolate) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors/interp.jl:49
 [8] impute!(::Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}, ::Impute.Interpolate) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors.jl:84
 [9] impute!(::DataFrame, ::Impute.Interpolate) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors.jl:172
 [10] #impute#17 at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors.jl:76 [inlined]
 [11] impute at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors.jl:76 [inlined]
 [12] _impute(::DataFrame, ::Type{Impute.Interpolate}) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/imputors.jl:58
 [13] #interp#105 at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/Impute.jl:84 [inlined]
 [14] interp(::DataFrame) at /home/synerzip/.julia/packages/Impute/GmIMg/src/Impute.jl:84
 [15] top-level scope at REPL[15]:1
```

and this error does not occur when I run the following code

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:a => [1.0, 2, missing, missing, 5.0], :b => [1.1, 2.2, 3, missing, 5])
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0      │ 1.1      │
│ 2   │ 2.0      │ 2.2      │
│ 3   │ missing  │ 3.0      │
│ 4   │ missing  │ missing  │
│ 5   │ 5.0      │ 5.0      │

julia> Impute.interp(df)
5×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.0      │ 1.1      │
│ 2   │ 2.0      │ 2.2      │
│ 3   │ 3.0      │ 3.0      │
│ 4   │ 4.0      │ 4.0      │
│ 5   │ 5.0      │ 5.0      │
```

now I know the reason but confused about how to solve it. I can not use eltype while reading CSV because in my dataset contains 171 columns and it typically has either Int or Float. stuck for how to convert all columns in Float64.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want:

1. something simple, that does not have to be maximally efficient
2. all your columns are numeric (possibly having missing values)

Then just write:

```
julia> df
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │ c       │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │ Int64?  │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.5      │ 1.65     │ 1       │
│ 2   │ 3.0      │ 3.3      │ 3       │
│ 3   │ missing  │ 4.5      │ 5       │
│ 4   │ missing  │ missing  │ missing │
│ 5   │ 7.5      │ 7.5      │ 6       │

julia> float.(df)
5×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ a        │ b        │ c        │
│     │ Float64? │ Float64? │ Float64? │
├─────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 1.5      │ 1.65     │ 1.0      │
│ 2   │ 3.0      │ 3.3      │ 3.0      │
│ 3   │ missing  │ 4.5      │ 5.0      │
│ 4   │ missing  │ missing  │ missing  │
│ 5   │ 7.5      │ 7.5      │ 6.0      │
```

It is possible to be more efficient (i.e. convert only the columns that are integer in the source data frame, but it requires more code - please comment if you need such a solution)

*EDIT*

Also note that CSV.jl has [`typemap`](https://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/#Typemap-1) keyword argument that should allow to handle this issue when reading the data in.